# return false is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created one form with dynamically created check box's . And i have used one j query script that will check weather user has checked at-least one check box or not .Tf it is not then it will alert the error message .

HTML Code

```
print "<form action=\"dpt_multi_delete.php\" method=\"POST\" name=\"searchform\"  >\n";

print "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"dptid$i\" value=\"$row[dpt_id]\"></td>\n";

print "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"DELETE SELECTED\" onclick=\"Validate()\"/>\n";
```

java script is :

```
function Validate() {
 var form = document.forms[0]
  var counter=0;
  for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length ; i++) {
    if (form.elements[i].type == "checkbox"){
      if(form.elements[i].checked == true){
   counter++
     }
    }
    }
    if (counter == 0){
     alert("You have not selected an item to delete");
      return false;
      }
   else{
     alert("Are you sure you want to delete  "+counter+" records");

     }
    }
```

Problem 1:
the problem what i am facing is if user is not selected any checkboxs then he will get error alert . after clicking that ok or cancel it is redirecting to dpt_multi_delete.php page. even i used "return false" after alert but its not working.

Problem 2:
if the user selected multiple checkboxes then i will alert the warning then if the user clicks ok then it will delete the record . but is all so deleting record after canceling that alert message .

what is the salutation for this . ?where i am wrong ?

Comment: You don't seem to have used any jQuery. The code that calls your function isn't doing anything with the return value. Try `onclick=\"return Validate()\"`

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to return false from an event handler function, then you need to do it from *the event hander* itself, and not just another function that it calls.

Your onclick function doesn't have a return statement. It calls `Validate` and then does nothing with the value that function returns.

```
onclick="return Validate();"
```

---

Convention reserves variable names starting with capital letters for constructor functions. Call your function `validate`, not `Validate`.

It is generally a better idea to handle this kind of test when the form is submitted rather than when a particular submit button is clicked.

Modern JavaScript doesn't use `onclick`/`onsubmit`/etc attributes. We use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

```
function validate(event) {
    // Your logic
    if (someCondition) {
        // Stop
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('submit', validate);
```

Comment: ya its working with selection part . but in deletion part if i cancel the error msg then all so its deleting .

Comment: @Nayana — That is a different problem entirely. But you want `confirm`, not `alert` (and you want to pay attention to the return value of confirm).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Add class to check box

```
print "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" class="mycheckbox" name=\"dptid$i\" value=\"$row[dpt_id]\"></td>\n";
```

jQuery function:

```
function Validate() {
  var counter=0;

  $( ".mycheckbox" ).each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
      counter++
    }
  });

  if (counter == 0)
  {
    alert("You have not selected an item to delete");
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Are you sure you want to delete  "+counter+" records");
  }
}
```